# Visual studio 2010, Setup license Windows XP/7

Tags: visual-studio, dialog

Visual studio 2010, Windows XP/7

I am not sure if I am doing right here but I have an application project with a (visual studio) Setup project.

I have created a license file, license.rtf to the App project and included it into the 
Setup project.

I have also added the "License" dialog box in the Setup project and added the license.txt 
file to the dialog box but when I rebuild the Setup project I get the following error message ?

```
Error   1   Unable to build dialog module named 'c:\Program Files (x86)\
                Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\Deployment\.\VsdDialogs\
                1033\VsdLicenseDlg.wid' 
                C:\svn\eis-damalini-easylink\EasyLink\Setup1\Setup1.vdproj  Setup1
```

I have also tried with an .rtf file but no success

/Stefan

Answer (score 3):

If the attached rtf file is created using Visual Studio itself, then there might be some encoding issues with the file. Hence create a new file using Microsoft Word and save the file as rtf.

I have solved my issue like this.

Comment: This did it for me. If you create the .rtf through VS, it gets encoded oddly. Open it with Word and re-save, worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a file that **does not already exist in your project output**. This error is usually because you selected a license file that is part of your primary output and it can't output the file twice to build the license dialog.

Add a separate file or ensure that it is not being deployed with your primary output.

1. Right-click your installer project -> View -> File System
2. Select "Application Folder".
3. In the right hand pane, right-click -> Add -> File
4. Add a file that is not part of your project, such as a completely separate rtf file.
5. Right-click your installer project -> View -> User Interface
6. Select the "Licence Agreement" dialog.
7. In the properties window select your licence file again.
8. Select the file you just added to the install file system.

NB: Make sure you delete any incorrect selection you have made, they will show up under your installer project with a red "invalid" icon. Even after adding a new separate file, the old one may still linger causing warnings in your build.

Example of what a conflicted file looks like in your project. The icon is actually for "exclude" but gives you a hint that your file isn't going to be available during the installer build.

[image: Conflicting license file that should be removed]